# Open modal with specific id

Tags: javascript, html, simplemodal, image-slider

If i click on the thumbnail of the following code, the general modal with an image slider opens but i can slide through **all images of all modals**. (Test here: https://www.hanki-testet.com/referenzen#erklaerfilme)

How do i modify the code to open the right modal for each project and only with the slides inside it?

I'm sure there is a way to address each modal's corresponding ID and only show the relevant images of the modal... I just don't know how.

I am so sorry for my bad JS knowledge ...

```js
// Modal Edited

$('.openmodal').click(function() {
$(`#modal${$('.openmodal').index(this) +1}`).addClass('visible');
});

$(".closemodal").click(function() {
  $(".modal").removeClass("visible");
});

$(document).click(function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest(".modal,.openmodal").length) {
    $("body").find(".modal").removeClass("visible");
  }
});


// Manual Slider

var sliderIndex = 1;

function setSlider() {
  showSliders(sliderIndex);
}
//slider image index
function plusSlider(n) {
  showSliders(sliderIndex += n);
}
//dot index
function currentSlider(n) {
  showSliders(sliderIndex = n);
}

function showSliders(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("manual-carousel");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    sliderIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    sliderIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[sliderIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}

//Manual Slide
setSlider();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <a class="closemodal">X</a>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <img class="manual-carousel" src="images/image1.jpg">
      <img class="manual-carousel" src="images/image2.jpg">
      <img class="manual-carousel" src="images/image3.jpg">
      <button class="prev" onclick="plusSlider(-1)">&#10094;</button>
      <button class="next" onclick="plusSlider(1)">&#10095;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="modal2" class="modal">
  <a class="closemodal">X</a>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <img class="manual-carousel" src="images/image4.jpg">
      <img class="manual-carousel" src="images/image5.jpg">
      <img class="manual-carousel" src="images/image6.jpg">
      <button class="prev" onclick="plusSlider(-1)">&#10094;</button>
      <button class="next" onclick="plusSlider(1)">&#10095;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="modal3" class="modal">
  <a class="closemodal">X</a>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <img class="manual-carousel" src="images/image7.jpg">
      <img class="manual-carousel" src="images/image8.jpg">
      <img class="manual-carousel" src="images/image9.jpg">
      <button class="prev" onclick="plusSlider(-1)">&#10094;</button>
      <button class="next" onclick="plusSlider(1)">&#10095;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- The elements that lead to the modals -->

<li>
  <a class="openmodal">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="images/thumbnail1.jpg">
    <p>Title</p>
  </a>
</li>

<li>
  <a class="openmodal">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="images/thumbnail2.jpg">
    <p>Title</p>
  </a>
</li>

<li>
  <a class="openmodal">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="images/thumbnail3.jpg">
    <p>Title</p>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. It gives error. Please fix to make a [mcve]

Comment: I would use data attributes: `<a class="openmodal" data-modal="#modal1">` and then `$(".openmodal").on("click", function() {
  const modal = $(this).data("modal");
  $(modal).addClass("visible");
});`

Comment: Thanks for your input, that worked on my modals and i can now open each modal on its own.

But still i can click through all images of all modals, with the difference that black frames can now be seen if the images are not within the opened modal. Do you have any idea how i can solve this problem?

Comment: You can see how it works on following site: https://www.hanki-testet.com/referenzen#erklaerfilme (scroll down to the gallery with the items "Fotos Slideshow")

Comment: As a new question, add the open to that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the modal based on the index of the link.

```js
$('.openmodal').click(function() {
    $(`#modal${$('.openmodal').index(this) + 1}`).addClass('visible');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that also worked very well! But I still don't know how to fix the slider issue where all sliders' entire images can still be clicked. Any idea?
I am so sorry that I have to tap into your know-how to solve my problem.